# How do KRACK patches fuction

Tags: security, wifi

Almost all vendors have released patches to defend devices- both clients and access points- against KRACK attacks (https://www.krackattacks.com).  Can anybody help me understand how these patches fix device vulnerability to KRACK?  I can find a lot of articles recommending workarounds, or recommending to patch your devices, but none that actually give any information about how those patches might work.

(Context: I'm trying to determine devices vulnerability to KRACK attacks from a wireless sniffer to let people know if they need to worry).

Answer (score 0):

The general attack vector for KRACK attack is replaying the M3 message in the 4 way handshake using the same key. Each time a vulnerable client receives this message it will reset its key replay counter and NONCE. This allows replay attacks - i.e. the same ciphertext encrypted using the same key but different NONCEs allows an attacker to eventually deduce the key that is being used.

So a patch to a vulnerable client would probably involve checking the key received in M3 messages, and if it's the same as was previously received, do not install it just silently ignore the message.